# Convert this Facebook JSON callback to grab images in directory

Tags: jquery, json, facebook

Facebook requires access tokens now to access public photos. I cannot build an app to deal with this, but I have 50+ galleries on a website that have broken and I'm trying to find the least painful solution.

Assuming I have all my images for a given album in a directory on my own server, can I modify this code to grab my images and throw each one into a list tag? Basically get images in a given directory from my server instead of Facebook and build out the list.

```
$.getJSON('//graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos?callback=?', function (json) {
    $.each(json.data, function () {
        $('<li></li>')
            .append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + this.images[1].source + ') center no-repeat; background-size: 140%;"><a href=' + this.images[0].source + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>')
            .appendTo('#album-gallery');
    });
});
```

Comment: What file names are you giving to your photos on your server? How will your client know which photos to show? What server side language are you using? You are not able to traverse the directory on the client; your server will have to *tell* the client which files are available.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough to answer your questions. All I know is if I have a directory with image_01.jpg through image_20.jpg or whatever, I would like it to return this in the html:

    <li>image_01.jpg</li>
    <li>image_02.jpg</li>
    <li>image_03.jpg</li>

Answer (score 0):

From [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388647/convert-this-facebook-json-callback-to-grab-images-in-directory/16389094?noredirect=1#comment23490517_16388647), you can add the images `01.jpg` to `20.jpg` programmatically, simply using a loop;

```
for (var i=1;i<=20;i++) {
    var url = '/pathToYourFolder/image_' + (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i + '.jpg';

    $('<li></li>')
        .append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + url + ') center no-repeat; background-size: 140%;"><a href=' + url + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>')
        .appendTo('#album-gallery');
}
```

Note that we've substituted the URL's you were adding before to the images with our own construction of `url`. You'll need to change `/pathToYourFolder/` with the name of the folder your're now storing your images in.

If you then decide you want images 1- 30, or 5- 10, you just need to change the ranges of the `for` loop.

---

To address your [comments on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388647/convert-this-facebook-json-callback-to-grab-images-in-directory/16389094?noredirect=1#comment23891999_16389094);

1. You can avoid having to insert the script at the bottom of the page by wrapping it in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) block.
2. If you have a number of file names, you can store them in an array, and iterate over them like so;

   ```
   var names = ['anything.jpg', 'foo.jpg', 'bar.jpg', 'baz.jpg'];

   for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
       var url = '/pathToYourFolder/' + names[i];

       $('<li></li>')
           .append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + url + ') center no-repeat; background-size: 140%;"><a href=' + url + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>')
           .appendTo('#album-gallery');
   }
   ```

Combined with the `$(document).ready()`, this would give you;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = ['anything.jpg', 'foo.jpg', 'bar.jpg', 'baz.jpg'];

    for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        var url = '/pathToYourFolder/' + names[i];

        $('<li></li>')
            .append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + url + ') center no-repeat; background-size: 140%;"><a href=' + url + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>')
            .appendTo('#album-gallery');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked! I had to put the script at the bottom of the page before the </body> to get it to work. Is there an easy variation that would use 'any' image, no matter what the file was named... like 'anything' + .jpg ?